# How to check if function is partial in Scala?

Tags: scala, partialfunction

I have a method that receives a function, but that function may be partial, in such case I don't want it to fail with MatchError.

```
def doSomething[X,Y](opt:Option[X])(f:X=>Y)={
  f match {
    case p:PartialFunction[X,Y]=> opt.flatMap(p.lift) //This doesn't seem to work
    case _ => opt.map(f)
  }
}
```

That way I can use the method like this

```
doSomething(x){
case t if predicate(t) =>  otherMethod(t)
}
```

so in case I don't have a predicate, I can use it like
this `doSomething(x)(otherMethod)` instead of

```
doSoemthing(x){
case t=> otherMethod(t)
}
```

Note: Looking for a solution that doesn't require catching `MatchError` exceptions

Comment: Why not always receiving an `X => Option[Y]`?

Comment: On the other hand, you may do something dirty like `if (p.is InstanceOf[PartialFunction[X,Y]]) opt.flatMap(p.asInstanceOf[PartialFunction[X,Y]].lift)`

Comment: I already tried that. It just doesn't work. If the compiler expects a total function, it doesn't matter if it's written as a partial function, it will compile a total function, so `.isInstanceOf[PartialFunction[X,Y]]` always returns false.

Comment: Why not go the other way and accept only partial functions: `def doSomething[X,Y](opt:Option[X])(p:PartialFunction[X,Y]) = opt.flatMap(p.lift)`? For "in case I don't have a predicate", you can write `doSomething(x)(otherMethod(_))`.

Comment: Wow, Didn't know that was possible

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, indeed, it doesn't work.

Comment: You are right, I should have tested it. I misremembered the relevant rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for partial function has been changed since 2.9 per SLS 8.5, so that even you do `{ case x => y}`, it DOES NOT mean it is a partial function. Its type will be exact as you define it as.

In your case, you defined it as `X=>Y` (as in your function parameter), so it is just a `X=>Y` (it got compiled into a regular function, and non match cases will throw MatchError), and even you do `isInstanceOf[PartialFunciton[_,_]]`, it won't match.

To make your scenario work, you can just simply cast the passed function as PartialFunction, like:

```
doSomething(Some(1))({case 2 => 0}: PartialFunction[Int,Int]) //This returns None without MatchError
```

while

```
doSomething(Some(1)){case 2 => 0} //This gives MatchError and it is not recognized as PartialFunction inside the body
```

This is probably not as convenient as you thought it is, but it is the only way to make it work. (or you define 2 separate functions for either case, like `collect` and `map` in standard library)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer because I don't think that what you want is possible in Scala.

The original method is fine and works as expected, though it could be a bit simpler:

```
def doSomething[X, Y](opt: Option[X])(f: X => Y): Option[Y] = {
  f match {
    case p: PartialFunction[X, Y] => opt.collect(p)
    case _ => opt.map(f)
  }
}
```

The problem is here:

```
doSomething(x){
  case t if predicate(t) =>  otherMethod(t)
}
```

Scala is creating a `Function` rather than a `PartialFunction` from that `match` expression so the test is failing. If you pass a real `PartialFunction` the method works OK.

```
val p: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case i: Int if i > 0 => i
}

doSomething(Some(0))(p) // Returns None
```

I don't think there is any way of doing what you want, mainly because `doSomething` has multiple argument lists which messes up type deduction for the second argument list.

My suggestion is just to use

```
x.map(f)
```

or

```
x.collect{
  case ...
}
```

as appropriate in the calling code.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what you are passing as a Partial Function, but definitely you should have to define it with specific signature like this:

```scala
val positive: PartialFunction[Int, Option[Int]] = {
  case x if x >= 0 => Some(x)
  case _ => None
```

The `positive` function is defined only for positive numbers. In case of negative numbers, the function returns None and you won't get scala.MatchError in runtime.

This specific function enables you to access to `isDefinedAt` method which is testing dynamically if a value is in the domain of the function.

postive(5).isDefinedAt // true

poistive.isInstanceOf[PartialFunction[Int, Option[Int]]] // true

I demonstrated here why you are always getting false when you check `p.isInstanceOf`

```scala
def doSomething[X,Y](opt:Option[X])(f:X=>Y)={
  f match {
    case p if p.isInstanceOf[PartialFunction[X,Y]] =>
    println("I'm a pf")
    println(s"Is it PartialFunction: ${p.isInstanceOf[PartialFunction[X,Y]]}")
    opt.map(p)
    case _ =>
    println("I'm not a pf")
    opt.map(f)
  }
}

doSomething[Int, Option[Int]](Some(5))(positive) // partial function case

doSomething[Int, String](Some(5)) { // tricky case
  case s => s.toString
}
```

You can play with it [here:](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Bunyod/X1rv2Vs4R76hVwKiwROMWQ/37)

Comment: Why downvote could you please explain the reason, if I understand the question correctly, how can we use isInstanceOf[PartialFunction[X, Y]] correctly.

Comment: That is not the question.

Comment: However, my answer covers both sides, read the author's comments below question. But read the title of question!

Comment: 1. A partial function that returns options is a redundancy. 2. If I inline `positive` then your example fails. 3. I'm trying to remove boilerplate (as seen in my last example), so extracting the lambda and adding explicit type annotations defeats all the purpose. 4. I'm not trying to understand how PartialFunctions work, but trying to find a way to inline a partial function and have the compiler actually compile a partial function and not a "total function" that fails on certain input.